# How does: $−i2nπ∓iz=arccosh(4) $ lead to, $z=arccos(4)=2πn±iarccosh(4)?$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm confused by this step in a calculation:

$arcosh(4)=−i2nπ∓iz$, 
which leads to: 
$z=arccos(4)=2πn±iarcosh(4).$

From this I understand multiplying the LH expression by $i$ gives: 
$i.arcosh(4) = 2n\pi \pm z.$

But how do I move the $\pm$ in front of the $iarcosh(4)$? Some say it's because $cosh(x)$ is an even function, but it doesn't explain the $\pm$ for me. If someone could demonstrate this through a proof, it'd be very helpful!
Thanks.

this is related to: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3592434/760727)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply $arcosh(4)=−i2nπ∓iz$ by $\pm 1$ and dividing by $i$ and writing $\pm 2n\pi $        as $2n\pi$ as $n$  being any integer will take care of $\pm.$   Just rearrange the expression as $z=...$

Comment: Never come across that trick before! Learn something new everyday. Thanks!